# Several debugging profiles for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

Sometimes I want to run my program with argument *X*, and other times with argument *Y*.

I know I can change the debugging arguments in Project properties -> Debugging -> Command arguments.

But this means I have to change them manually every time I want to switch between arguments.
I'm wondering if there is something similar to IntelliJ run configuration, where you can define several ways to run a project (with different arguments if you want to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is something similar to IntelliJ run configuration, where you
>   can define several ways to run a project (with different arguments if
>   you want to).

Yes, in vs2017 you can use [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2017) to create your new configuration(Copy settings from Debug config) And for different configuration, you can edit corresponding argument for them.

1.Right-click your solution in Solution Explorer, choose Configuration manager,in the drop-down list of solution configuration choose new to custom your new config, and for the goal of debugging, I suggest you copy settings from debug.

2.Right-click project->properties,you can define different arguments for different modes:

[image]

3.Save and if we want to use debug mode with different configuration, we can use the window below:Choose ConfigX to use argumentX, ConfigY to use argumentY, since they all copy settings from debug, they have no other difference except argument.

[image]

Hope it helps.